# finding out if all the digits of a number are equal

Tags: arrays, c, global-variables, equality, function-definition

So I want to start by saying that I already solved the problem, but there is something that is bugging me,

Here is the code first:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int flag = 1;

int controlNumber(int);

int main() {    
    int array[10] = { 233, 45, 777, 81, 999999, 36, 90, 88, 11, 61 };   
    int i;  
    int c;  

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d >>  ", array[i]);
        c = controlNumber(array[i]);
        if (c == 1) {           
            printf("all digits are equal\n");
        } else {
            printf("not all digits are equal\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int controlNumber(int a) {
    int q = a;
    int r = a % 10;
    int temp;
    
    while (q != 0) {
        temp = q % 10;
        if (temp == r) {
            q = q / 10;
        } else {
            flag = 0;
            return flag;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

The code works only if the global variable `flag` is made local inside the scope of the function `controlNumber` with a value of `1`, and I can't really figure out why that is the case since the logic should still be the same.

Also, I'm still a beginner to some extend so I apologize for any indentation errors.

Comment: This is one of these problems that are better to be solved in "reverse". You get one digit of the number, say it is `8`. Now just repeatedly check your number against `8`, `88`, `888` and so on, till it becomes less than it or equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables retain their value. In your case, if `flag` is global, once set to `0` (within `controlNumber`) it will keep that value. There is no other place in the code to make it `1` again.

Making it a local variable to the function will cause it to initialize to `1` every time the function is called.

**Edit:** if you want to have it as global, you could set it to `1` every time `controlNumber` returns `0`, i.e., before or after `printf("not all digits are equal\n");`.

Answer (score 4):

For starters it is a very bad idea to define a function that depends on a global variable. In fact it is the reason of the bug of your program. You forgot to reset the global variable flag to 1 each time before calling the function.

The function can be defined the following way without any redundant global variable

```
int controlNumber( int n )
{
    const int Base = 10;

    int digit = n % Base;

    while ( ( n /= Base ) && ( n % Base == digit ) );

    return n == 0;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int controlNumber( int n )
{
    const int Base = 10;

    int digit = n % Base;

    while ( ( n /= Base ) && ( n % Base == digit ) );

    return n == 0;
} 

int main(void) 
{
    int array[] = { 233, 45, 777, 81, 999999, 36, 90, 88, 11, 61 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d >>  ", array[i] );

        if ( controlNumber( array[i] ) )
        {
            printf( "all digits are equal\n");
        }
        else 
        {
            printf( "not all digits are equal\n" );
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
233 >>  not all digits are equal
45 >>  not all digits are equal
777 >>  all digits are equal
81 >>  not all digits are equal
999999 >>  all digits are equal
36 >>  not all digits are equal
90 >>  not all digits are equal
88 >>  all digits are equal
11 >>  all digits are equal
61 >>  not all digits are equal
```

If for example you will change the constant `Base` in the function and make it equal to `8`

```
int controlNumber( int n )
{
    const int Base = 8;  //10;

    int digit = n % Base;

    while ( ( n /= Base ) && ( n % Base == digit ) );

    return n == 0;
}
```

then you will get the following result.

```
233 >>  not all digits are equal
45 >>  all digits are equal
777 >>  not all digits are equal
81 >>  not all digits are equal
999999 >>  not all digits are equal
36 >>  all digits are equal
90 >>  not all digits are equal
88 >>  not all digits are equal
11 >>  not all digits are equal
61 >>  not all digits are equal
```

In this case for example the number `45` has the same digits in the octal representation because in the octal representation the number is written like `055`.