# Very simple task in theory, but I still don't understand what I am doing wrong

Tags: python

Task:

> A natural number is given. Write a program that determines whether a given number consists of identical digits.

My solution:

```
num = int(input())
same = False
a = 0

while num != 0:
    last_digit = num % 10
    if last_digit == a:
        same = True
    else:
        a += last_digit
    num = num // 10

if same == True:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: Once `same` is True, it can never become False - that doesn't seem right.

Comment: @slothrop points out a problem with your approach.  Another approach is to convert this answer to Python [finding out if all the digits of a number are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178918/finding-out-if-all-the-digits-of-a-number-are-equal/66179099#66179099)

Answer (score 3):

You started from the wrong point. For the number to consist only of identical digits, all must be equal. That means the the proposal will be false in one single digit is different. So you should start with `same = True` and in the loop, set it to `False` and break immediately out of the loop if one digit is different. And you should correctly initialize `a` the a valid value *before* the loop and then never change it:

```
num = int(input())
same = True           # initialize same to True
a = num % 10          # and a to the last digit

while num != 0:
    last_digit = num % 10
    if last_digit != a:
        same = False
        break
    num = num // 10

if same == True:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simplest to convert to a string and use a Set which removes duplicates:

```
if len(set(str(num))) == 1:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

Comment: A set is a bit more concise. `if len(set(str(num))) == 1:` ...

Comment: @slothrop  Yes,  even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "a" is what you are comparing each digit to. Because a = 0, you are going to return false every time since num cannot == 0.

In this case I would try comparing last_digit to num // 10 each time.

```
last_digit = num % 10
same = "YES"
while num != 0:
    if num != last_digit:
        same = "NO"
    num = num // 10
print(same)
```

I'm fairly new to Python scripting so this may be completely incorrect, but this is my guess based on past experiences.

Comment: Think about the last iteration of the loop. On that last iteration, `num` is 0 by the time the `if` statement is reached, so the `num != last_digit` check won't do what is intended. Also, think about the iterations where `num` is more than 1 digit long: `num != last_digit` cannot be true then either.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a issues understanding what you're doing try breaking the problem into smaller parts. It often helps seeing things clearer.

Anyways, an "exotic" workaround would be this (although a few things could be simplified):

```py
    number = input("Give a natural number: ")
    answer = True
    division_reference = int(number) // int(number[0])
    for digit in number:
        division_result = int(number) // int(digit)
        if(division_result != division_reference):
            answer = False
    
    if(answer == True):
       print("Identical")
    else:
       print("Different")
```

Comment: This throws a `ZeroDivisionError` if the number contains a zero.

Comment: You're right. I didn't think about that one, neither did I properly handled potential other issues (although I the goal was to give a simple idea). Anyways, thank you for notifying me.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm has a few problems, one of them being if the digits are the same, you set `same = True`, but if the digits are not the same, you did not set `same = False`.

It is better to assume that all digits are the same, then if you found they are not, set `same = False` and immediately exit the loop because you don't need any further calculations.

Here is my code:

```py
number = int(input("Enter a natural number: "))

same = True
number, reference = divmod(number, 10)

while number != 0:
    number, last_digit = divmod(number, 10)
    if last_digit != reference:
        same = False
        break

print("YES" if same else "NO")
```

Notes

- I use the very last digit as a `reference` for all digit comparisons
- I use the `divmod()` function to simplify the operations. For example: `divmod(281, 10) --> (28, 1)`